# How do I make my router IP address a url for localhost

Tags: php, linux, flutter, localhost

I'm using flutter and I'm trying to get an image from a WordPress website. The WordPress is on localhost, the response body returns the image url like http://localhost:8888/wp-json/my-image-url. But this returned url won't be displayed on the flutter app.(Socket exception errno=111). The only thing that can work is to use my router IP address 192.168.0.103 (for real device) or 10.0.2.2 (for emulator).

I also tried using a domain name for the localhost:8888 it returned http://mydomainname/wp-json/my-image-url but it didn't work on my app as it shows hostname not found.

Is there a way to make the response look like http://192.168.0.103:8888/wp-json/my-image-url. And also make my url 192.168.0.103:8888/wp-admin permanently. Because using the IP address opens my WordPress site but somehow loops back and changes the url to localhost:8888/wp-admin.

Heard of mapping the localhost to an IP address but I haven't found any useful solution.  I use Linux I don't know if it's the same with windows os.

[This is what I want my response to be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHpa9.jpg)

[And not mydomain-name or localhost:10039](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKWnt.png)

Comment: Port forwarding does not help? (Router Setting)

Comment: You'd need to forward the port from your router to your local machine. That's configured in your router settings (if it supports the feature). But that opens your computer up to anyone on the internet who happens to find it (and eventually, they will). Don't do that unless you're certain you are confident in dealing with the security implications - it's not a trivial decision. Also be aware that your IP address is likely to be dynamic and change sometimes (how often depends on your ISP), so hard-coding that into your app might not work very well. Dynamic DNS service could help you with that.

Comment: If you want external access to your site via the internet, then the better solution is to host it on an internet-facing server which is properly configured for that. There are a billion-and-one cheap Wordpress hosting providers out there. You might even find a free one, if you don't mind questionable performance and lots of ads embedded in your site. Your localhost should be your development / testing environment only, so you can try out changes and ensure they work before putting them live for everyone to access.

Comment: Tried port forwarding. Didn't help. Just so you know I only want to use it to test my app. I only want to url to change so as to have it run on my flutter app since my phone and system are connected on the same router.

Comment: If both devices are connected on the same router then you need to use the LAN IP of your computer, not the public Internet IP of the router.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to change the base URL in your WordPress settings

Comment: Changing the baseUrl worked.  Thank you so much